# Deadlocks caused by concurrent deletes on different rows on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I need some help to understand this deadlock scenario. We have concurrent deletes on a table. The operations  deletes a record and insert a new one in a transaction (other tables are involved but no locks are reported on the deadlock graph). The concurrent operations are NOT targeting the same rows. The xml doesn't show a page lock neither. I don't understand why the deadlocks are happening. It happens either using Read Committed or Read Committed Snapshot isolation levels.

Here is the deadlock graph and xml:

```
xml_report  
<deadlock>
    <victim-list>
        <victimProcess id="process111c0a04e8"/>
    </victim-list>
    <process-list>
        <process id="process111c0a04e8" taskpriority="0" logused="988" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594052476928 (cdccc9664fb5)" waittime="572" ownerId="402767" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2023-08-09T15:56:06.700" XDES="0x113940c428" lockMode="S" schedulerid="6" kpid="32656" status="suspended" spid="67" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2023-08-09T15:56:06.753" lastbatchcompleted="2023-08-09T15:56:06.743" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.743" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="W3737985" hostpid="0" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="snapshot (5)" xactid="402767" currentdb="5" currentdbname="bcecm" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="112" sqlhandle="0x02000000f1caf30cb9946dc3186f8369fd94f3a26b002a540000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
                <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>  (@P0 nvarchar(4000))delete from Documento  WHERE id = @P0   </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="processb8de6eca8" taskpriority="0" logused="988" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594052476928 (cdccc9664fb5)" waittime="572" ownerId="402796" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2023-08-09T15:56:06.767" XDES="0x113430c428" lockMode="S" schedulerid="9" kpid="36848" status="suspended" spid="68" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2023-08-09T15:56:06.823" lastbatchcompleted="2023-08-09T15:56:06.813" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.813" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="W3737985" hostpid="0" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="snapshot (5)" xactid="402796" currentdb="5" currentdbname="bcecm" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="112" sqlhandle="0x02000000f1caf30cb9946dc3186f8369fd94f3a26b002a540000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
                <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>  (@P0 nvarchar(4000))delete from Documento  WHERE id = @P0   </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process1117804108" taskpriority="0" logused="988" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594052476928 (1af84d4c4a2b)" waittime="99" ownerId="402813" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2023-08-09T15:56:06.780" XDES="0x1142190428" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="34780" status="suspended" spid="72" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2023-08-09T15:56:06.830" lastbatchcompleted="2023-08-09T15:56:06.823" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.823" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="W3737985" hostpid="0" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="snapshot (5)" xactid="402813" currentdb="5" currentdbname="bcecm" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="112" sqlhandle="0x02000000f1caf30cb9946dc3186f8369fd94f3a26b002a540000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
                <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>  (@P0 nvarchar(4000))delete from Documento  WHERE id = @P0   </inputbuf>
        </process>
    </process-list>
    <resource-list>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594052476928" dbid="5" objectname="bcecm.dbo.documento" indexname="PK__document__3213E83FFA04E697" id="lock113213f500" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594052476928">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="processb8de6eca8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process111c0a04e8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594052476928" dbid="5" objectname="bcecm.dbo.documento" indexname="PK__document__3213E83FFA04E697" id="lock113213f500" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594052476928">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process1117804108" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="processb8de6eca8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594052476928" dbid="5" objectname="bcecm.dbo.documento" indexname="PK__document__3213E83FFA04E697" id="lock112348fb80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594052476928">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process111c0a04e8" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process1117804108" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
    </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Are you using explicit transactions (i.e. the delete and insert are wrapped in a BEGIN TRANS and END TRANS), and also, are you using a rowlock hint with the delete statement (i.e. DELETE FROM TableName WITH (ROWLOCK) WHERE ...)? In your XML I don't see a hint for the delete, which may help.

Comment: You may also want to explicitly set the Serializable Isolation level before the transaction, using SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

Comment: What does the execution plan look like? Is the `id` column type `nvarchar(4000)` as the parameter type suggests?

Comment: @DanielG, in fact I'm using Spring data with the Transactional annotation. This graph was collected using a test program on my local machine that simulates the production load with 15 threads executing the same operations for a couple minutes. Tried the WITH (ROWLOCK) hint but it made no difference. The SERIALIZABLE level got things worse, more queries got involved on the deadlock with this level.

Comment: Rowlock will likely get upgraded to page lock anyway, so it will probably not solve your problem, it's just a hint not a fixed rule

Comment: Design suggestion, but since you're doing a delete and then an insert, is it possible to covert that to a single update of the existing row? I might be way off as I don't know your situation. You can check the @@RowCount on the update and run and insert if you need to.

Comment: @siggemannen, the strange fact is that are no page locks. All waitresource are KEY not PAGE. But all the ids are different so I can't understand what's going on.

Comment: @DanielG, I thought about it, but I need to change the id wich is not updatable. I would need to change the primary key to another column  and it would need a lot of refactoring. It's my last option. But although I'm not really experienced with deadlock graphs I can't see the insert query involved on the deadlocks.

Comment: I'm guessing in Spring Data, your method is annotated with the @Transaction decorator? Aside from that, I think looking at the query executing plan and index optimizations is worth a shot.

Comment: What does the execution plan for the `DELETE` look like? Also what are the additional statements that are happening in the same transaction as the `DELETE`? Can see there are some because of things like `lasttranstarted="2023-08-09T15:56:06.700" lastbatchcompleted="2023-08-09T15:56:06.743"  lastbatchstarted="2023-08-09T15:56:06.753"` for session 67

Comment: Analyzing the query plan xml I finally found the cause. The table had a foreing key targeting another column on the same table. The deadlock graph shows that the deadlock occurs because of the primary key but in fact was because of this FK. Removing the FK and controlloing referencial integrity on the application solved the problem. Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

After a careful look on the execution plan of the deletes I found what might be causing the issue. The table had a foreing key targeting another column on the same table (it is a hierarchical entity). The deadlock graph shows that the deadlock occurs on the primary key but in fact it was caused because of this FK. Removing the FK and controlling referencial integrity on the application solved the problem.